# Getting Linear Regression score from Transfer Learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, transfer-learning

I am having a task of assigning a score from 0.0 to 1.0 to images. For this I have made use of already learned models meant for classification of ImageNet competition like VGG, SqueezeNet etc. From the output of the convoluted layers of this models, I have added my own 2 or 3 dense layers (fully connected layers), with the first few layer having a certain 'x' hidden units and last layer having only one unit. The value coming from this last layer (having one unit), I am using as score.

I am performing retraining on all the dense layers, but after I perform training, I get a constant score of around 0.75 for whichever input I send. 
I have a good training set of 50000 images.

Please can somebody explain me where I am going wrong in this approach. Also, some directions on how to proceed in this type of problem will be very helpful.